# Quova TCP Keepalive? Pipelining?

Tags: ruby, keep-alive, pipelining, quova

One of my developers is reporting that the connection rate to our Quova servers has become a bottleneck.  He reports that his attempt to set the TCP keepalive option in our Ruby code doesn't seem to be honored.

I haven't yet looked at our code; but I'm curious if anyone here could offer advice, based on the vendor's [sample Ruby request code](http://developer.quova.com/docs#sample_ruby) on how to refactor it to make many questions over each connection (or otherwise eliminate/bypass the apparent bottleneck).

I'm painfully aware that I may be missing the right keyword or even whole concept here.  RTFM is fine so long as you point me at T (right) F-ing M.

Comment: The link to your sample request code is behind a secured host.

Comment: Doh!  My mistake; Total cut-n-paste flub.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Quova's load balancer was configured to turn off keep-alive.